# Where do you get a live cd for ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Ive made some mistakes on my computer. I want to wipe in and install ubuntu. Help please i really want a fresh computer.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/114818)

Comment: The install dvd doubles as a live dvd.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dvd-writer and dvd, you can get ubuntu at:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download

You can also buy a dvd at:

http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17